# TCP/IP over CrazyRadio PA, zigbee, or other `802.15.4` WPAN Mesh Network

Tags: networking

I'm planning to build a set of Pi's to act as motion detect cameras, and I want to connect them together in a mesh network with a longer range than standard wifi.
Has anyone ever used the CrazyRadio PA adapter for TCP/IP connections in a Pi?  Is it possible set this or a similar adapter (APC220 or XBee Pro) up as a TCP/IP network adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do this type of thing is still being designed/developed. There are a few official proposals and competing draft standards, but nothing set in stone (as of mid 2017).

There is one way to experiment with this on Raspberry Pi, [6loWPAN](http://wpan.cakelab.org/) is a proposed ipv6 specification (by TI) to use over various WPAN (802.15.4) radios. It is already part of linux kernel, but still very experimental on raspberry Pi - [there is a tutorial available](https://github.com/RIOT-Makers/wpan-raspbian/wiki/Create-a-generic-Raspbian-image-with-6LoWPAN-support), however it will require building a custom kernel image.

If your camera software requires an IP port to use, there are other ways to tunnel the traffic through the mesh network. In the simplest case these wireless radio networks show up on the raspberry pi as a tty (serial port), the utility `socat` can be used to expose a serial port as a network port and connect a network port to a serial port.

#### extras

- [dated discussion of IP over 802.15.4 from linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-linux-talks-internet-things-look-ieee-802154)
- [802.15.4 wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4)
- [Zigbee-IP - competitor standard to 6loWPAN](http://www.zigbee.org/zigbee-for-developers/network-specifications/zigbeeip/)